# Specifying filepath for jenkins image gallery plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to get https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Image+Gallery+Plugin to work. However, every single attempt to get it to work just tells me:

```
Creating image galleries.
Creating archived images gallery.
This build has no artifacts. 
Skipping image gallery in this build.
```

The documentation is sparse and the 3 types of image galleries available:

`Archived images gallery`, `In folder comparative archived images gallery` and `Multiple folder comparative archived images gallery`

make no sense to me.

The only thing I can make heads or tails of are the arguments: one requires an "include pattern", another requires a "base root dir".

According to the plugin,

> You can use wildcards like 'module/dist/**/*.zip'. See the includes attribute of Ant fileset for the exact format. The base directory is the workspace. You can only archive files that are located in your workspace.

Which links to http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html

I am storing my screenshots at `/workspace/selenium/screenshots/a_screenshot.png`,

but the following don't work:

Include pattern:

```
**/*.png
*.png
selenium/screenshots/*.png
```

Base root dir:

```
selenium/screenshots
/selenium/screenshots
/selenium/screenshots/*.png
/selenium/screenshots/*.png
```

And I've run out of ideas to try. Has anyone used this plugin successfully before, and how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Being unfamiliar with Jenkins terminology, I was unaware that "archived images" actually required me to "archive the artifacts" in the first place!

Adding another post-build step to archive the screenshots made them available for the image gallery.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer here. Feel free to update the plug-in Wiki with this information, or file an issue you may have found.

Comment: I am having some issues with the paths as well.  When I use "Archived images gallery" and specify **/*.png I get all the images.   However when I use "In folder comparative archived images gallery" and specify a base folder, it displays the folders but the paths to the images are missing the base folder from their path and it also includes a 'archive' folder in the path.  This results in all the images being broken (and therefore useless).

Were you able to get it to work for more than just "Archived images gallery"?

Comment: Hi @darkrat! I feel really bad reading your comment just now :-(. If you can file an issue in issues.jenkins-ci.org, I will work on this issue and will try to push a new version. Working on image-gallery plug-in right now, and looking for open issues, questions here, etc.